# Excel VBA Runtime 1004 error on Autofill when running on another PC

Tags: vba, excel

I could really use the fountain of knowledge here!

I have a VBA encrusted spreadsheet which I'm telling to autofill a formula across a variable range.  It works perfectly on my PC but fails on a colleagues.

The error is: Run time error 1004

The code is:

```
Sub FillFormula()    

Dim BOBdate As Date 
Dim Bobrow, lastrow As Integer

lastrow = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count + 2

BOBdate = Sheets("BOB Pivot").Range("a3").Value

Cells.Find(What:=BOBdate, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=iferror(INDEX('BOB Pivot'!R2C1:R50000C50,MATCH('Rooms Daily'!RC2,'BOB Pivot'!R2C1:R50000C1,0),MATCH('Rooms Daily'!R3C,'BOB Pivot'!R2C1:R2C50,0)),0)"

BOBrow = ActiveCell.Row

With ActiveCell
    .AutoFill Destination:=Range("G" & BOBrow & ":AJ" & BOBrow), Type:=xlFillDefault
    .AutoFill Destination:=Range("G" & BOBrow & ":AJ" & LastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
    .AutoFill Destination:=Range("G" & BOBrow & ":G" & LastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault

End With

End Sub
```

Is there anything obvious without uploading the entire workbook?!

I am a noob to vba so if the coding is terrible, please keep the giggles on the inside!

Thank you

Tom

Comment: Replace activecell with the range you need

Comment: Thank Karthick, unfortunately it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved... amended the way in which the autofill spreads

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell the code is okay. When you run the workbook on a colleagues computer try to run from the same path as your computer, if possible. Otherwise, save the workbook on your computer to a default system location that is the same on both computers and try again.

Comment: Thanks Matt, unfortunately it didn't work... It's so weird... could office version create an issue here?

Comment: Maybe, if going between Office 2003 and 2007.